# D3 bar chart formation

Tags: d3.js, label, bar-chart

Good afternoon.

I have some doubts in the axis constructor and labels alignment.´
My data is something like this:

```
var data = [[1,1.5],[2,2],[3,2.5],[4,3],[5,3.5],[6,4],[7,4.5],[8,5]];7
```

My doubts is:
1) How I can align the xAxis labels in the middle of the bars;
2) Reverse the direction of the yAxis and join the extremes of the axis x and y
3)Insert the xLabel the lower right corner of the chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/qAHC2/645/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the first, you have to compute the position of the bars taking into account the width of an interval and the width of the bars:

```
.attr("x", function(d) {return x(d[0]) + x.rangeBand()/2 - 40;})
```

For the second, you need to reverse your y scale (SVG y coordinates start at the top) and adjust the way the bars are computed accordingly:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
  .range([height, 0]);
// ...
bars.attr("y", function(d) {return y(d[1]);})
  .attr("height", function(d) {return height - y(d[1]);})
```

You can join the two axes by adjust the offset of either of them. Similarly, you can put the x label where you want it in this way:

```
.append("text")
.attr("x", width)
.attr("dy", 20)
.attr("text-anchor", "end")
.text("Foo");
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qAHC2/646/).

Comment: Thanks, one more doubt.
Where I can add the title of the bar (center on the top)?

Comment: This question, and many more, are answered in [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/).